# D3 - elements claim to be undefined

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, data-visualization

The code receives JSON packets through a websocket, and should use D3 to make a scatter graph of them:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="visualisation">
    </div>
</div>

<script - websocket stuff>
// Handle incoming messages
socket.onmessage = function (message) {
// Decode the JSON
    var  data = JSON.parse(message.data);
    var  source = data.source;
    if (data.type === 'Client Data') {
        var value = JSON.parse(data.value);
            graphData(value);
    };
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var margin = {top:20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left:50},
         width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
         height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.scale.linear()
         .range([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scale.linear()
         .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
         .scale(x)
         .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
          .scale(y)
          .orient("left");

    var svg = d3.select("#visualisation").append("svg")
          .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right);

function graphData(data) {
    console.log("graphdata called")

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.time; }));
    y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.value; }));

    svg.append("g")
         .attr("class", "x axis")
         .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
         .call(xAxis)

    svg.append("g")
         .attr("class", "y axis")
         .call(yAxis)

    svg.selectAll(".dot")
         .data(data)
         .enter().append("circle")
             .attr("class", "dot")
             .attr("r", 3.5)
             .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.time); })
             .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.value); });
};
</script>
```

The javascript falls over claiming that it cannot find the attribute 'domain' of x (`x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.time; }));`. However, commenting this line out, reveals the same problem for y, on the line below, and for the following line (`svg.append("g")`). I have copied this example from an online tutorial, with the exception of the graphdata function. The example read from a csv, whereas this receives data from a websocket. As a result, the error is likely to be in this function, but I am not certain.

Comment: What happens if you put your scale definitions inside your `graphData` function?  Might be a scoping issue.

Comment: Most likely, the problem is with this line: `<script - websocket stuff>` -- you cannot just dump extra characters inside an html element tag and expect the browser to know what to do with it...

Comment: @SteveR That was to make the stackoverflow post shorter, as I'm certain that the 'websocket stuff' does work. It's not like that in the actual code!

Comment: @pmkro If I move the scale definitions inside, it claims that it cannot read property 'linear' of undefined, in this line: `var x = d3.scale.linear()`

Comment: @Alex I'm assuming you're using v3? The syntax in v4 is different.

Comment: @pmkro Ah, no, I'm using v4. Would you recommend moving to v3, or changing the syntax to work with v4?

Comment: @Alex I would change the syntax to v4. [Here is a master list of the changes](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md). But a few to start are `d3.scale.linear` is now just `d3.scaleLinear`

Comment: @pmkro Great, thank you very much!